# My App become halt when I click UISearchController Swift 5

Tags: swift5

UISearchController on navigationbar was working fine , but after some time when I was trying to implement searcher functionality on home controller this problem occurs. Then I undo all things but same thing is happening.App works fine but as so as I click on UISearchController on top of navigationbar, the app goes on halt. 
The same problem is occurring on other controllers also..What I do plz help me out

Comment: can you share some code because it's hard to answer just from question.

Comment: Thanks for consideration...I turn off my Xcode and run again ,and  it works again